# React Native render white screen when use Context API

Tags: react-native

I have an issue.
When I don't wrap AuthProvider everything OK. Dont have any problems.
But when I wrap AuthProvider, my Application render white screen @@.
So I check terminal, and see Bundle not running ( normally when render we can see Bundle Loading and Running...) .
How I fix this problem ?
Thank you so much.

createDataContext.js

```
   import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = ({ chilrden }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};

    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {chilrden}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };
  return { Context, Provider };
};
```

AuthContext.js

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  authReducer,
  {},
  { isSignedIn: true }
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider as AuthProvider} from './src/context/AuthContext';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';



import AccountScreen from './src/screens/AccountScreen';
import TrackDetailScreen from './src/screens/TrackDetailScreen';
import TrackListScreen from './src/screens/TrackListScreen';
import SigninScreen from './src/screens/SigninScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import TrackCreateScreen from './src/screens/TrackCreateScreen';



const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup:SignupScreen,
    Signin:SigninScreen
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    trackListFlow:createStackNavigator({
      TrackList:TrackListScreen,
      TrackDetail:TrackDetailScreen
    }),
    TrackCreate:TrackCreateScreen,
    Account:AccountScreen,
  })
});

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return(
    <AuthProvider>
      <App/>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Put your code as text, not as images

Answer (score 1):

you make mistake in spelling just check your spelling in your code you will find  {chilrden}

Comment: while that is a spelling error, OP has used the same spelling in all places in the code. That wouldnt be the cause

Comment: mistake in spelling :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe `boundActions` is re-created every time the app render that cause the problem. You should try to use `useMemo` to cache `boundActions`. It may help

Comment: Fixed. This problem is coming from props @@. when I edit {children} to props . and pass as props.children everything will be ok :)) .But I can't understand why ? lol =))).

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:
in createDataContext.js ( `const Provider = ({children})` )
Use `props` instead of `{children}` 
Pass as `{props.children}`

My quick fix:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = props => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};

    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }

    console.log(props.children);

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };
  return { Context, Provider };
};
```